# Finish date not calculating correctly

Tags: ms-project-2010

If I entered a duration time of 2 days, start date of 20.03.2019 and finish date being automatic schedule, MS Project shows finish date as 21.03.2019. But I want it to count two days after the start date; it should be 22.03.2019.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

> a duration time of 2 days, start date of 20.03.2019...MS Project shows finish date as 21.03.2019

This behavior is correct.

If you start a two-day task on Wednesday, you will finish on Thursday. To see how this is true, change the date format* to show the **date and time** to see that the task starts at the beginning of the day (e.g. 20.03.2019 8:00) and finishes at the end of the day (e.g. 21.03.2019 17:00).

*To change the date format go to File: Options: General tab

Answer (score 0):

MS Project is calculating correctly. A 2-day duration task will start at 20/3/2019 9:00 and finish at 21/3/2019 at 17:00 (or whatever the calendar states as the end of the working day).

This is expected behavior of MS Project.

If you add a successor task, it will start at 22/3/2019 (given that the predecessor task concludes at the end of the day, so there is not remaining time to start the next task the same day).

However, if you want to force the task to end at 22/3/2019, you can trick MS Project by defining the task’s start date as “20/3/2019, 10:00 am” (yes, including the start time – use the time format according to your locale). This way, the task will start at 20/3/2019, 10:00 am, and finish at 22/3/2019, 10:00 am. Then, any successor task will start at 22/3/2019, 10:00 am. Note, however, that this could cause some confusion with team members or other project stakeholders.

Greetings.